# Using font of a chapter for a heading

Tags: formatting

Is there a way to use the font of a \chapter{} without actually being a chapter?

[image]

```
\chapter{Sperrvermerk}

{\LARGE \textbf{Sperrvermerk}}\\
```

As you can see they are not matching.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `\chapter*{Sperrvermerk}`? The `*` suppresses the chapter number.

Comment: Look at your document's class definition of `\chapter` and copy the title font.

Comment: But if not then `\LARGE\textbf{\textsf{Sperrvermerk}}` should do it, `\textsf` selects the 'sans serif' font.

Comment: What heading are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

If you're unable to guess the font from the code in the class file or packages loaded, you can always ask LaTeX to tell you.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\chapter{\expandafter\string\the\font}

\end{document}
```

You get

[image]

Thus you know that the font is in the sans serif family (`cmss`), it is boldface (`bx`) and upright (`n`). The size is 20.74pt; in order to guess what font size corresponds to it you can use a similar strategy:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showsize}[1]{\texttt{\string#1:} {#1\expandafter}\f@size\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\showsize{\Huge}
\showsize{\huge}
\showsize{\LARGE}
\showsize{\Large}
\showsize{\large}
\showsize{\normalsize}
\showsize{\small}
\showsize{\footnotesize}
\showsize{\scriptsize}
\showsize{\tiny}

\end{document}
```

A bit of trickery, but that's not important: you get the correspondance you need.

[image]

Running the same file, but with the `10pt` option to the document class would yield

[image]

Now you know that you get the same font by

```
\huge\sffamily\bfseries
```

Let's try it:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Sperrvermerk}

{\huge\sffamily\bfseries Sperrvermerk}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that you are using a KOMA-Script class. Set the font for titles
to `\rmfamily`!

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Sperrvermerk}

{\huge \textbf{Sperrvermerk}}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

or use `\sffamily` fot the default text.